# Duplicated without take care about type of unknowns values

Tags: python, pandas

There is a way to use `pandas.DataFrame.duplicated` without compare different types of `None, nan, <NA>` etc...

In other words, if there is `None` and `nan` they should be equals.

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution to the problem...